get all entries that do not have a specific child entry
I have this ldap scheme.
dc=company, dc=com
    - ou=users
        - uid=aaaa  
            - ou=car 
                - brand=audi  
                - brand=chevrolet  
        - uid=bbbb  
            - ou=car
                - brand=ford  
                - brand=audi  
                - brand=chevrolet 
        - uid=cccc  
            - ou=car
                - brand=ford   
                - brand=chevrolet 
        - uid=dddd  
            - ou=car
                - brand=ford  
                - brand=audi  

I need to get only users who don’t have ford car. It is possible to do it in one request ?
Thank you

It's kind of possible if you only need the DNs (and if your exclusion criteria also happens to be based on DNs), but not if you need non-DN attributes.
If all necessary data (both for the the child entry you want to exclude, and the user you want to find) is stored in DNs:

Do a global search for the child entries, e.g. (&(objectClass=car)(brand=*)) (requesting no attributes).
Use your LDAP client's functions to parse/unparse or split/join DNs, to map each result's DN into its parent(parent) entry DN, which is the user's DN.
Gather all user DNs into a set.
Loop over the earlier (childDN, userDN) results, every time the childDN is a "brand=ford" remove the userDN from the set.

If child entries have to be matched by a non-DN attribute, then an additional search to find (brand=ford) entries is needed (and then step 4 is "if childDN is in the badCars set, remove the respective userDN from the goodUsers set").
If you need to retrieve non-DN attributes, then at least one additional search to load users' attributes is needed. With Active Directory you can construct a filter like (|(distinguishedName=DN1)(distinguishedName=DN2)(...)) that lets you retrieve several users by their DN at once.

thank you for the solution, but what about performance ? imagine i have 1 millions entries (users) : making a such request (get ALL) will be disastrous for my App. It is possible to do Paging like we do on classic database to get a small bunch of data ?

Well, I would imagine that if you had 1 million users, you wouldn't be keeping them all under a single OU – multiple OUs, with one query per OU, would be the first step to scaling – and perhaps all those users would not be in LDAP at all. (Consider that any problems you're having, the admin/management tools would have had already, and the directory would have been rearchitectured to avoid those problems before you got there.)

That aside, it depends on your LDAP server – some support the LDAP "Paging/VLV" control, some don't, I don't remember offhand whether Active Directory does. And I suspect it would be quite possible to write an application that processes the search results incrementally, since they arrive as individual items, not as a single "all or nothing" result – the LDAP client is able to read e.g. 1000 at a time even without paging. (This is how initial DB replication works, after all – and if I had to deal with a massive directory, I'd probably start by mirroring it into a "traditional" DB...)
